# How to use CSS grid to create 3x3 grid but place items in specific grid columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout that looks like this:

[image]

The blue blocks are `divs`. It's essentially a `3x3 grid` but with gaps in the 3rd and 4th grid column.

How can I create a gap within CSS grid to achieve this layout? I've tried it with `flexbox`, but couldn't achieve the above, so hoping a `grid` layout is the answer.

Here's my code:

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". . ."
    ". . ."; 
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say " It's essentially a 3x3 grid but with gaps in the 3rd and 4th grid column" but your image shows a 3x2 grid with gaps in the third and first column. Could you explain a bit more what you want? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS grid allows you to choose which row and column an element will start in (and indeed, though not needed in your case, how many columns/rows it is to span).

This snippet gives the 3rd and 4th children of the wrapper specific grid positions.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Note: just for a demo it has also introduced a non-zero grid-gap. The grid-area settings have been removed as not needed if the above method is followed.

Comment: if you only add grid-colum:2 to the #3 it should be enough

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of the CSS grid solution with only the necessary code:

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap:5px;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column:2;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification, but I can't work out why item4 is put into row 2 when if we said nothing at all about its positioning it would go into column 3, but on row 1. Help!

Comment: @AHaworth it would do that if you use `grid-auto-flow: dense;` but the `sparse` algorithm will place it there. A bit tricky but if you have time I invite to read this to better understand the placement algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64751030/8620333

Comment: Great, many thanks, will read it.

Answer (score -1):

How about padding/margin?

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  display: inline-grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0 0; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". . ."
    ". . ."; 
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 2px 0;
  width: 55px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  margin: 1px !important;
  background: #1657c9;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.item-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 38%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: normal;
}
.item-3, .item-4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1"><span class="item-text">1</span></div>
  <div class="item item-2"><span class="item-text">2</span></div><br>
  <div class="item item-3"><span class="item-text">3</span></div>
  <div class="item item-4"><span class="item-text">4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: really bad use of css coding. If you ahve a grid, you can make use of `grid-template-area` or `grid-row/column`. No need to be hacky by trying to find out the right margins and paddings aswell as hardcoing a linebreak.

Comment: It works fine, and was easy. I recommend this code

Comment: I don't. Does work fine does not eman that you coded claen. You coded super hacky. The whole purpose of grid is not to hardcode the grid through HTML with a linebreak. And having to sue `!important` is also a good indicator that you code is problematic in the long run. Of course it is easy to make a hole in a wall by smashing a drill through it. The right approach would be to use the drill to drill a hole...

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:
This is HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1"> </div>
<div class="div2"> </div>
<div class="div3"> </div>
<div class="div4"> </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.parent {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
      grid-column-gap: 0px;
      grid-row-gap: 0px;
    }

    .div1 {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
      background: blue;
      height: 3rem;
      margin: 1rem;
    }

    .div2 {
      grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
      background: blue;
      height: 3rem;
      margin: 1rem;
    }

    .div3 {
      grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
      background: blue;
      height: 3rem;
      margin: 1rem;
    }

    .div4 {
      grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
      background: blue;
      height: 3rem;
      margin: 1rem;
    }
```

[image: grid]