# grid-row-start/grid-row-end puts item in wrong column

Tags: css, css-grid

Why is it that the below `grid-row-start`/`grid-row-end`  code puts **Item #2** in the 1st column?  Nothing was said about columns. The intent is that Item #2 should remain in its 2nd column but take up two rows. The code works if I try this with Item #1: it takes up two rows and remains in its own column, but not Item #2. Item #2 is moved to the front, the 1st column.

```css
.container {
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item-grid {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 200, .2);
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.container-grid-example {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    width: 50%;
}

/* This works with :nth-child(1), the 1st item */
.container-grid-example :nth-child(2) {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container container-grid-example">
        <div class="item-grid">1</div>
        <div class="item-grid">2</div>
        <div class="item-grid">3</div>  
        <div class="item-grid">4</div>
        <div class="item-grid">5</div>
        <div class="item-grid">6</div>
        <div class="item-grid">7</div>
        <div class="item-grid">8</div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is to use `span 2` and not define the lines.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item-grid {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 200, .2);
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container-grid-example {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  width: 50%;
}


/* This works with :nth-child(1), the 1st item */
.container-grid-example :nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-grid-example">
  <div class="item-grid">1</div>
  <div class="item-grid">2</div>
  <div class="item-grid">3</div>
  <div class="item-grid">4</div>
  <div class="item-grid">5</div>
  <div class="item-grid">6</div>
  <div class="item-grid">7</div>
  <div class="item-grid">8</div>
</div>
```

To understand what's happening, you need to refer to the placement algorithm to know when each element is placed: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo

You will notice the steps like below:

> 1. Position anything that’s not auto-positioned.
> 2. Process the items locked to a given row.
> 3. Determine the columns in the implicit grid.
> 4. Position the remaining grid items.

In your case, no need to consider (3) because you don't have any implicit grid. We also don't have items "not auto-positioned" so we will consider the (2) and the (4).

In your example, the second item is locked to a given row so it belongs to the step (2) thus we first position it then we consider the remaining items in steps (4).

When using `span 2`, the element is no more locked to a given row so it belongs to the step (4) like all the items and we follow the document order to place all of them so we logically start with the first one then the second one and so on.

---

Some related questions:

[CSS Grid : How Auto placement algorithm works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64198236/8620333)

[CSS Grid Item Placement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68595914/8620333)

[Using CSS GRID Why Im getting this gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64746869/8620333)

Comment: Yes, it'd be nice to have an explanation why the original code doesn't work, since it's counterintuitive, thanks

Comment: @geneb. add the explanation

Comment: Thanks a ton. I had a slightly different issue. I had a 4x2 grid. A bunch of children. And one needed to span two rows. It had `grid-row-start: 1` in it. Setting `grid-row-end: 2` had no effect. Setting `grid-row-end: 3` made it take up two rows instead. This was odd and inconsistent. I took a wild shot and googled. Found your solution. Thank you.