# CSS "grid-template-areas" not working as desired

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I thought that when I type `.` (blank field) inside `grid-template-areas` property, `.item5` will show inside `under` field. However it showing inside `.` field. Why does it works like that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item1  {
  grid-area: header;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: content;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: left;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: footer;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "content ."
                       "left ."
                       "footer footer"
                       "under under";
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px; 
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your expectation.

Comment: Just curious, but did you forget to link your css in your HTML file with a link tag?

Comment: @Sam You don't do that in Stackoverflow snippets. The snippet functionality connects the parts in the background for you.

Comment: The `.` is meant to be used to leave grid cells empty. Since you have an unplaced cell, it is placed in the first cell that is empty.

Comment: @connexo but I dont understand 5 should be place inside under, there are five declared rows no?

Answer (score 2):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-template-areas-property):

> A sequence of one or more "." (U+002E FULL STOP), representing a null cell token.

and

> A null cell token represents an **unnamed area** in the grid container.

unnamed area doesn't mean that an item cannot be placed there. It simply mean *unnamed* and the automatic placement algorithm will start from the top to the bottom so the first empty area for `item5` is an unnamed area.

You can follow the full algorithm here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo where you will find no restriction about unnamed area or the named one. If your `item5` was alone it will get placed into the first row/column (the one named "header")

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item1  {
  grid-area: header;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: content;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: left;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: footer;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "content ."
                       "left ."
                       "footer footer"
                       "under under";
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px; 
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Related question where I am giving a more detailed explanation about the placement algorithm:

[CSS Grid : How Auto placement algorithm works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64198236/8620333)

Comment: Of course you are right, but I think that the OP missunderstanding comes from another point (May be I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I think that you are expecting to have **grid-auto-flow: column;**, but this is not the default style.

I added it to the snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item1  {
  grid-area: header;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: content;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: left;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: footer;
}
.grid-container {
grid-auto-flow: column;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "content ."
                       "left ."
                       "footer footer"
                       "under under";
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px; 
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: even with a column flow, the logic remain the same, if for example we swap the Dots with the named area, the 5 will be placed inside a dot: https://jsfiddle.net/fo3w65yh/. It's probably what the OP want but let's hope he will not understand that using a column flow will change the logic related to unamed area.