# CSS Grid Columns not Wrapping

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a particular arrangement of `HTML` elements, that I'm successfully positioning with the use of CSS Grid to look as follows:

[image]

The top of the `Form Input` here is in line with the bottom of `Heading One`

The problem is that when the screen is resized, I expected the right hand column to wrap under the first column - as the left and right columns have a min and max width of 300px - but it doesn't. The 2nd column just shrinks in width...

I don't have much control over the HTML layout here, so was looking to solve via grid layout

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 300px));
  column-gap: 96px;
}

.title {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
}

.details {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}

.form {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.message {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

div {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        Heading One
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        This can contain a lot of text potentially. This can contain a lot of text potentially. This can contain a lot of text potentially
   </div>
   <div class="form">
       Form Input
   </div>
   <div class="message">
       All is good
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `@media` queries to do this. You have defined the grid area your `title`, `details`, `form` and `message` elements should be in. `min-` `max-` width only defines the context of the column within the grid.

Comment: there is no wrapping because you are explicitly defining the row position of each one so it should be respected all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not define the position to have wrapping. Do it like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 35%)); /* use bigger than 33% to have max 2 columns */
  column-gap: 96px;
}
.details,.title {
  grid-column: 1; /* put title and details on first column */
}
.details {
  grid-row: span 3;
}


div {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        Heading One
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        This can contain a lot of text potentially. This can contain a lot of text potentially. This can contain a lot of text potentially
   </div>
   <div class="form">
       Form Input
   </div>
   <div class="message">
       All is good
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Drenai you need to understand the full auto-placement algorithm to get it. I wrote a few answers on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64199156/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/68596190/8620333

Comment: Those links are very helpful, thanks. I see how it's working now